# Проблемы с компиляторами/сборкой c++ программ

Tags: mingw, компилятор

MSVS 2008 portable : Компилируется c++ файл. Успешно. При запуске .exe Вылетает ошибка:

> this application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Review the manifest file...

Codelite Проблема с make:

---

> g++.exe: @Axa.txt: No such file or directory
>   g++.exe: no input files
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/Axa] Error 1
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2

---

MinGW - компилирует, на выходе получаю .exe. При запуске он просто "висит";

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>

    using namespace std;

    class X 
    {
        private:
            string name;

        public:
            void SetName()
            {
                cin >> this->name;
            }
            void GetName()
            {
                cout << this->name;
            }
    };

    int main()
    {
        X X1;
        X1.SetName();
        X1.GetName();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Код вешающегося exe в студию!

Comment: @gbg Добавил в описание.

Comment: @gbg MinGW g++ с любым кодом так. Ошибки он ловит. всегда висит .ехе

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете какие-то портабельные помои восьми (восьми, Карл!) летней давности.

Скачайте нормальную VS Community Edition 2015. Или Qt Creator, в нем тоже все есть.

Comment: Ага. Все не так просто. Мне не под силу пока скачать столько. У меня трафик мобильный 3г.

Comment: @Бигиннер тогда все становится намного интереснее.
Qt Creator вместе с mingw (но без Qt!) весят мегабайт 300 - потянете?

Comment: Да. Но вот почему ни один из всех компиляторов не смог? =) Может и от QT тоже так будет, тот же mingw. Я хотел поработать только с gcc. Но пришлось IDE ставить. Кстати, если скомпилировать C исходник, то .ехе работает как надо. Странно все это. =)

Comment: я бы поспорил что ms vc 2008 это плохая версия. Я лично тна более новые не перехожу, мне она больше нравится, даже на 2005 можно.